# glDrawArrays - Getting GL_INVALID_OPERATION and GL_INVALID_VALUE

Tags: opengl, emscripten, gldrawarrays

I am porting some legacy OpenGL code to Web Assembly (using emscripten).  This is using OpenGL 1.1

I have two vertex formats, and I swap between them (depending on whether I'm doing 2D drawing or 3D drawing).  Here are the two formats:

```
struct Vertex2DRef
{
    float           mX;
    float           mY;
    float           mZ;
    unsigned int    mDiffuse;
    float           mTextureU;
    float           mTextureV;
};

struct Vertex2DNRef
{
    float           mX;
    float           mY;
    float           mZ;
    float           mNX;
    float           mNY;
    float           mNZ;
    float           mTextureU;
    float           mTextureV;
};
```

This is old, legacy code, so I'm just drawing straight from memory buffers.  When I'm drawing 2D, I do this (Don't mind the XGL wrapping, it's just a define to also report if the call is producing errors):

```
        XGL(glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY));
        XGL(glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY));
        XGL(glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY));
        XGL(glDisableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY));
        
        int aStride=sizeof(Vertex2DRef);
        Vertex2DRef* theRef=(Vertex2DRef*)theBuffer; // <- The incoming vertices are in "theBuffer"
        
        XGL(glVertexPointer(3,GL_FLOAT,aStride,&theRef->mX));
        XGL(glNormalPointer(GL_FLOAT,aStride,NULL));
        XGL(glColorPointer(4,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,aStride,&theRef->mDiffuse));
        XGL(glTexCoordPointer(2,GL_FLOAT,aStride,&theRef->mTextureU));
        XGL(glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES,0,theTriangleCount*3));
```

So the above works... I get my render exactly as I expect them.

HOWEVER: When I try to draw the other vertex format, the one with normals, but no diffuse:

```
        XGL(glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY));
        XGL(glDisableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY));
        XGL(glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY));
        XGL(glEnableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY));
        
        int aStride=sizeof(Vertex2DNRef);
        Vertex2DNRef* theRef=(Vertex2DNRef*)theBuffer;

        XGL(glVertexPointer(3,GL_FLOAT,aStride,&theRef->mX));
        XGL(glNormalPointer(GL_FLOAT,aStride,&theRef->mNX)  );
        XGL(glColorPointer(4,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,aStride,NULL));
        XGL(glTexCoordPointer(2,GL_FLOAT,aStride,&theRef->mTextureU));

        XGL(glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES,0,theTriangleCount*3))
```

Now, I get nothing at all.  That glDrawArrays line drops two errors-- GL_INVALID_OPERATION and GL_INVALID_VALUE.  The reasons the documents list for those possible errors don't even apply (confirmed that theTriangleCount is not negative, and I don't use glBegin or glEnd anywhere in the program at all.

Can anyone help?

Comment: OpenGL 1.1 has extremely limited functionality. Consider using OpenGL 3.3+.

Comment: No, OpenGL 1.1 is capable of doing this.  It works when compiled in Win32, Android, and IOS.  I am trying to figure out what quirk is making it fail in Web Assembly.

Comment: Oh, if it's a platform-specific issue it's more complicated, I think.